# How to conditionally deploy an app.config based on build configuration?

Tags: .net, deployment, configuration, msbuild

I have three custom build configurations { Dev, Qs, Prd }. So, I have three app configs { Dev.config, Qs.config, Prd.config }. I know how to edit the .csproj file to output the correct one based on the current build configuration.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
   <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
</Target>
```

My problem is, I need to have **six** build configurations { Dev, Qs, Prd } x { Debug, Release }. I need to support the debug and release settings (optimizations, pdb, etc) for each environment. However, the app config values don't change between debug/release.

How do I keep the build script as generic as possible and use only the three app configs? I don't want to hard code too many conditional strings.

Comment: The "<Target/>" tag supports a "Condition" attribute. Can I test if the condition matches "Dev_*" (as in "Dev_Debug" or "Dev_Release") to use the Dev.config file?

Comment: Here is a nice <a href="http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx">Discussion at scott Hanselmans</a> about automating the multiple configuration. In the comments section there are some alternative solution's. Some interesting like working with delta of the config files. Some other are like having different config files for different environment.

Comment: Just for reference for future readers: I tried the code above and it worked, but NOT for deployment using ClickOnce. It just wasn't included. Thus I went for the solution from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/09/tricks-with-app-config-and-clickonce-deployment-saurabh-bhatia.aspx, which is similar to Steve's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Dev_Debug' OR '$(Configuration)'=='Dev_Release'" >
    <CfgFileName>Dev</CfgFileName>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- similar for Qs & Prd -->
<Target ...>...$(CfgFileName).config...
```

Comment: This works until I add the 3rd custom build config. I get an error: cannot find <blah>\.config. I think this may be a problem with my environment. I question whether I want to maintain this much .csproj config though.

Answer (score 9):

We fixed this using the Choose element in the csproj file. We have several different configurations set up so all we do is drop this block into your proj file and you can use VS's Configuration to help you out. I do want to second Rob's advice to move passed app.config. I have been moving in that direction for some time.

```
  <Choose>
<When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="Release\App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
<Otherwise>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Release\App.config">
      <Link>App.config</Link>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Otherwise>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that your question reveals that you have outgrown `app.config`--it is time to move on to a better solution, and to begin addressing some related issues.

For one, you should NEVER automatically deploy a configuration file to production, and you should expect the operations support personnel to vehemently reject any attempt to do so.  Of course, if you are the operations support personnel, then you should reject it yourself.  Instead, your release should include some instructions for manually updating the configuration file, with a sample for illustration.  Production configuration is too important for lesser measures, unless you simply don't value your production system much.

Likewise for test and other environments, but to a lesser degree, so you really only need your `app.config` populated for your own development work.

An option is to embed the multiple configurations into a single `app.config`, which is reasonable for small, relatively unimportant applications or in early stages of development/release.  For example, create a configuration setting called something like `target-env` that contains a value that you use in your code to select other configuration settings, such as by prepending the value onto the keys of the other configuration settings.

My preference is to move past `app.config` altogether, or to use it minimally.  In this case, I prefer to put just enough configuration data into a file to allow my application/system to connect to its database(s), then I put the remaining configuration details into a special database table for that purpose.  This has lots of advantages, such as making the database "aware" of what environment it represents (dev, test, production, etc.) and keeping the configuration and the other data together.  The deployment package can then properly be kept dumb regarding configurations and environment differences--the code just accesses its configuration data and acts accordingly, so the same deployment package is good for any environment.

However, a key success factor to this approach is that your application code must "know" what it expects for configuration and it must "know" to reject an improper/incomplete configuration.  This is where you should spend your time, not trying to work around the limits of `app.config`.

That usually means creating your own class for accessing configuration data, then using that class throughout your application instead.  This also leads to many other benefits, such as strongly-typed configuration data:  instead of a `String`, return a `DateTime`, or a `Url`, or an `Integer`, or a `Currency`, or whatever best fits the configuration data and the application.

Comment: There are 10-15 config items: a URL, a list of remote objects, a list of files. I am separating the source of config from the format by interface. The app config is the likely and expected source.

I prefer manual update as part of the build process, but I have to investigate this path for my boss.

Comment: "For one, you should NEVER automatically deploy a configuration file to production" Try telling that to Microsoft! Some of the stuff they stick in the app/web.config file these days really ought to be compiled into the exe file.

Comment: Yes, well I have found it fruitless to try telling Microsoft anything--I just try to protect myself and my client from the impact.  This is a perfect illustration of the necessary changes when you make the transition to an enterprise-class deployment.

Comment: I agree with most of the above except that it's taking a leap to imply that app.config only suits the most simple configurations. Are you proposing that one implement a custom configuration solution? In this case, what of professional grade technologies which rely on configuration management, such as WCF, web applications, etc? The needs definately exists. As for operations support denying automatically deployed config files - the point is well made that you shouldn't deploy something which is likely to be changed in operations, however many developers set their own policies in this respect.

Comment: @RobWilliams Could you please explain why is it so bad to deploy app.config file automatically?

Comment: "For one, you should NEVER automatically deploy a configuration file to production," Is your opinion, period. Tons of people use CI to deploy changes to production several times a day (like this website)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a build server?
Its been a long time since I've worked in .NET but can't you use Hudson(-like) server for managing your build configurations? Isn't it easier?
And what about NAnt? Doesn't it suit your needs?

Comment: James, you're right. At this point, we've outgrown the capabilities (and sensibilities) of using the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

The last solution I would like to employ is to create 6 app configs, 1 per custom configuration

{ `Dev_Debug.config`, `Dev_Release.config`, `Qs_Debug.config`, `...` , `Prd_Release.config` }.

Although, with that setup, I could maintain the generic build script, using no conditional strings.