# Environment Picker

Tags: c#, environment

is there any open source or use Environment Picker in dotnet that allows me to simply create a set of environments (whatever that may mean to my application) and then have a picker on startup.

it wouldn't be too hard to build a simple custom one but i would imagine that this is done over and over in every company so wanted to see if there was one put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at app.config files.  They are XML files which contain user or application settings.  You'll be able to specify different application (read-only) settings at compile-time.  Additionally, you'll be able to specify user settings at runtime.

I use app.config files to save and load things like window positions and other user preferences.  I know many people store things like database connection strings, file paths, etc, in app.config.

Here's a simple [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810043157/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx).

Comment: i mean having different settings for different regions, environemnts (production, uat, dev)

Comment: sure, you can have more than one app.config file and swap them out for each build.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that you will find such prebuilt functionality, or that it would satisfy you if you did find it.

You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350377/deploy-an-app-config-based-on-build-configuration#350571) relevant.

Bottom-line:  you will probably be happier and find it to be quicker to build your own.

However, someone just mentioned Spring for .NET, which you should investigate.