# project building with and without boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, msbuild, propertysheet

I have a project that can use boost library and it can also not to use it. 
I have a property sheet `use_boost` that can be added to the project and there are set the path to boost and a `<PreprocessorDefinitions>` tag with value `I_AM_USING_BOOST`.

In the code I have something like:

```
#ifdef I_AM_USING_BOOST
   #include <boost/any.hpp>
#else 
   #include <string>
#endif


namespace test
{


#ifdef I_AM_USING_BOOST
  using my_defined_type = boost::any;
#else
  using my_defined_type = std::string;
#endif


}
```

So if I do not want a build with boost, I remove the property sheet.
If I want to build with boost, I add the property sheet to the project.

Now, I want to build both variations of the library: one using boost and one not using boost.

Can I have a single project with two different builds: one with boost and one without boost, but not manually add or remove the property sheet?

I build using msbuild from a batch file.

Comment: I am not following. How are you using this type later? Using `std::string` and `boost::any` commands very different patterns.

Comment: Yes you can, create two different targets in the project and set the properties for each target.

Comment: you could also provide the property via command line to msbuild with `/p:<property>=<value>`

Comment: @SergeyA it is actually defined like std::map< std::string, boost::any > or std::map< std::string, std::string >

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606660/does-msbuild-recognise-any-build-configurations-other-than-debugrelease and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714668/how-do-you-pass-conditional-compilation-symbols-defineconstants-to-msbuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for me, I've added a new project configuration (Release_no_boost) and in that configuration I've removed the property sheet using boost library.

So, in the batch file I can now run msbuild for both variations by calling different configurations.
I have now in the batch file:

```
msbuild /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release D:\projects\some_test\test_1\test_1.vcxproj
msbuild /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release_no_boost D:\projects\some_test\test_1\test_1.vcxproj
```

This can be also used for a solution with multiple project, but it is needed to be created a solution configuration and for each project in the solution that is build, it is set the project configuration that is wanted.

Difference in batch is that instead of the project file it is given as parameter the solution file:

```
msbuild /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release D:\projects\some_test\some_test.sln
msbuild /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release_no_boost D:\projects\some_test\some_test.sln
```