# Visual studio custom build configuration working mechanism behavior Debug/Release or something else?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a query like when we build a project in visual studio we got default two configs debug and release...and both have different behavior  let say release is more optimize than debug.

But when we go for custom configuration and do not select copy setting from debug and release and left with empty then if we build solution how compiler does stuff here....like debug / release or something else....what kind of binaries will get after build ?

Please help...[image]

Comment: `PlatformTarget` and `AssemblyName` are defined in your `csproj` file. If you haven't update it, default values will be used for custom build config

Comment: You can also look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606660/does-msbuild-recognise-any-build-configurations-other-than-debugrelease)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you left everything empty, the default `Configuration` and `Platform` will be used. You can find it by examining your `csproj` file

```
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
  ...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And you'll need to specify the same for your custom build configuration