# How to use the final {project}.exe.config file when creating a setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I have created a console application (blah.exe) with specific app.config's for dev and prod. These are named `dev_app.config` and `prod_app.config`. I have hooked up an `AfterBuild` target in my csproj file<sup>*</sup> which copies the correct config file to the bin directory as `blah.exe.config`.

I have also created a setup project for this console app but I have run into a slight issue. It seems that the setup project uses the actual `app.config` from the project directory as opposed to the final `blah.exe.config` (located in bin directory).

```
|--Bin
|  |--Debug
|     |--Blah.exe.config <--- I want the setup project to use this file
|--app.config <--- Setup project uses this file at the moment
|--dev_app.config
|--prod_app.config
```

**How can I force the *setup project* to use the final config file generated in the bin folder and not the actual `app.config` file?**

*Additional Information:*

*My current solution involves adding another `AfterBuild` command which overwrites the actual `app.config` file. I don't like approach since it forces me to have an additional file that I don't need. Also, having this file has caused me some grief already since I made changes to the `app.config` file which got overwritten when building. The question is about how to get the setup project use the final config file in the bin folder and **NOT** how to manage the config or ways to create a config file.*

<sup>*</sup> Adapted from [Deploy an app.config based on build configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/350377/268667)

Comment: Are you using DEBUG version for dev, and release for production? If so, you could take a look at using #if DEBUG http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx and maybe load the different config files based on that using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223161.aspx

Comment: @astander, yes `dev_app.config` for Debug and `prod_app.config` for Release.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing it this way.  Create the base .config file to be suitable for deployment.  Only create a special one for the Debug configuration.  Deploy the Release build.

Comment: @astander - please clarify, where would I implement your suggestion. In my console app? If so, that does not make sense to me since the correct file is copied to my bin folder.

Comment: @hans - that does makes sense to a degree, but what if I need to deploy a Debug release of my project (which I will need to for an initial POC) - the Setup project will use the prod ready version of the config file.

Comment: Easily covered by my recommendation.  Just don't do the special thing.

Comment: Assuming you're concerned with appSettings values, another option would be to use the "file" attribute to override the settings for debug scenarios.   <appSettings file="custom.config">.  Then create your own custom.config file in your debug folder to override values as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using that exact same scenario but I use the BeforeBuild instead of AfterBuild, and it has always been fine.  I have been doing this on both web and windows projects.  Below is the code I am using.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ConfigSourceFiles Include="Web.$(Configuration).config" />
      <ConfigDestinationFiles Include="Web.config" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ConfigSourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(ConfigDestinationFiles)" />
  </Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: whats the advantage of using BeforeBuild? If there is no difference, this is what I am doing atm...

Comment: This just made my day. It is the best solution I have found. Thanks

Comment: This snippet is very helpful for me in windows service setup creation.